Complexity of Sharps
I am studying sharps in set theory and I have clear the idea of what does it mean for some $x^\sharp$ to "exist", but I struggle to see the way to write the sentence "$x^\sharp$ exists" in the language of set theory. In particular, I would like to calculate the complexity of such a formula (let's say, for $x$ a real), that I guess could be $\Sigma^1_3(x)$ (or maybe lower? I always struggle a lot with complexity calculations). I thought of using the equivalent formulation of "there is a nontrivial elementary embedding $j$ from $L[x]$ to $L[x]$" but this one looks even worse because now I have something, $L[x]$, that is a proper class, and I am stating the existence of another proper class, $j$. If you could help me with this and/or give me advice on how to do it on my own the next times, it would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Luckily, you can replace the existence of a full embedding by the existence of an iterable mouse of some sort, which is a countable structure, so this becomes a statement about countable structures and countable-length iterations thereof.

@AsafKaragila ooh okay, that's a great way to see it, thanks Asaf!

$x^\sharp$ is a $\Pi^1_2(x)$-singleton, meaning that the set $X=\{x^\sharp\}$ is $\Pi^1_2$-definable with parameter $x$. You may follow mice characterization to see this as Asaf stated, but let me go more classically as stated in Kanamori's book. We can see that $y=x^\sharp$ if

$y$ is a theory of over the language of $\in,\ \dot{x}$ with countably many constant symbols, comprising the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}^- + (V=L[x])$ and first-order properties for indiscernibles (like, remarkability), and
For every countable well-order $\alpha$, the canonical model of $y$ generated from $\alpha$ as indiscernibles is well-founded.

You can see that the canonical model generated from $\alpha$ is countable when $\alpha$ is countable, so we can formulate the second statement in the language of second-order arithmetic. The canonical model is arithmetically definable, so the second statement is $\Pi^1_2$. (More precisely, it takes the form $\forall^1 \alpha [\Pi^1_1\to\Pi^1_1]$.) The first statement is arithmetical.
The claim '$x^\sharp$ exists' is $\Sigma^1_3[x]$ as you correctly stated. It cannot be lower, otherwise Shoenfield absoluteness implies $x^\sharp$ exists in $L[x]$.

Great, thanks! I have to say the mouse characterisation proposed by Asaf feels more natural, but they both lead to the same result so it's good to see it proved in two different ways!
